# GridPanel cell editing of type 'textfield'

Tags: editor, extjs4, textfield, gridpanel

I'm using a GridPanel with the 'CellEditing' plugin.
My editor cell is of type 'textfield'.

I have 2 questions:
I would like to change the background color of empty cells so that it would be easier to see where there are missing values.
When double clicking a cell, I would like to format the text of the textfield. How do I get to the textfield object?

Thank you,
Dana

Answer (score 0):

You might give the textfield an id property.

```
field: {
id: 'myId',
...
}
```

Access the field with

```
var objTextfield = Ext.getCmp('myId');
```

About the color, you must add or overwrite the CSS. You can set a config property 'cls' to a custom css class. See here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-cls